# Create Cookie in Controller, read cookie from Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cookies, model-view-controller

using MVC.

In one of my controllers I am creating a cookie like the following:

```
 Function Login(ByVal access_token As String) As ActionResult
   Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("access_token", access_token))
 End Function
```

I want to check the value of the cookie called "access_token" **client-side**,   in order to know the next step to take in javascript.

How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

I found the solution:

I just add this function in Javascript :

```
   function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
            var theCookie = "" + document.cookie;
            var ind = theCookie.indexOf(cookieName);
            if (ind == -1 || cookieName == "") return "";
            var ind1 = theCookie.indexOf(';', ind);
            if (ind1 == -1) ind1 = theCookie.length;
            return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind + cookieName.length + 1, ind1));
        }
```

and I call it on  `Document.ready()` with the name of the cookie that I want to retrieve like that:

```
if (ReadCookie("access_token") != '')
            { }
```